# animating weapon along with armature from character

Tags: animation

I am animating an attack animation. I have a character (mesh) and an armature for it. The weapon is in a different mesh with it's own bone.

I click on the armature and go into pose mode to make the animations in the dope sheet. However, I cannot animate the weapon so it follows my character's arms correctly.

The way I have it now is that the bone for the weapon is parented to the armature of the character. So if I move the hand it moves the weapon, which is fine. But when I want to move only the weapon for one frame, the weapon's position and rotation changes on every other animation and frame, ruining them.

I want to be able to swap which hand carries the weapon from time to time.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of parenting the weapon to the hand armature I would use object constrains. You constrain the Weapon to the Armature, than Blender will let you select which bone to constrain to. The nice thing about constrains is that you can keyframe their influance, so you can have the wepon copy the rotation of the hand for 30 frames but the moment you want to give it a specific rotation you can just key frame the influance at 0 and rotate it as you wish, same goes for position.

In order to have the weapon passed from one arm to another you can have 2 sets of location&rotation constrains in it, one for each hand. Than as you pass it from one hand to another you keyframe the influance from one constrain to the other.
Here is a quick demo I made:https://youtu.be/Tncqr_CbkdA

Obviously you'd want to put more time into it to make the transition sooth etc.
Personally I'd not use the rotation constrains and just set the rotation of the wepon by hand but I've set it up his way since this is how it works with parenting.

Comment: To be more specific, you can use the **child of** constraint.  it copies rotation and location, and makes it easy. :)

Comment: That's a smart way of doing it, I'm still a noob my self so I missed that. Using child of you only have 2 constrains and keyframe the affected axis tickcboxes. I learned something new my self :D

Comment: That's one of the cool things of blender, i think.  There's always something new to learn! :)